# Convert a text file into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, dictionary, key

I have a text file in this format:

```
key:object,
key2:object2,
key3:object3
```

How can I convert this into a dictionary in Python for the following process?

1. Open it
2. Check if string `s` = any key in the dictionary
3. If it is, then string `s` = the object linked to the aforementioned key.
4. If not, nothing happens
5. File closes.

I've tried the following code for dividing them with commas, but the output was incorrect. It made the combination of key and object in the text file into a single key and single object, effectively duplicating it:

Code:

```
file = open("foo.txt","r")
dict = {}

for line in file:
    x = line.split(",")
    a = x[0]
    b = x[0]
    dict[a] = b
```

Incorrect output:

```
key:object, key:object
key2:object2, key2:object2
key3:object3, key3:object3
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried already? What problems did you run into?

Comment: @Carcigenicate sorry, updated.

Comment: You should be splitting on colons to separate the key and value. Also, why are you assigning a and b to the same element? And splitting on commas doesn't seem necessary since you're already using `for line in file:`.

Comment: When I was attempting to give b the value of [1] it said it was not in range.

Comment: That's because you aren't splitting on colons. Don't take this the wrong way, but changing things arbitrarily just to silence errors is a terrible practice that leads to problems down the road. Think about what the code does before you rely on it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I agree. Dumb mistake by me there :). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m={}                            
for line in file:
    x = line.replace(",","")     # remove comma if present
    y=x.split(':')               #split key and value
    m[y[0]] = y[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
key_dict={"key":'',"key5":'',"key10":''}
File=open('/home/wangxinshuo/KeyAndObject','r')
List=File.readlines()
File.close()
key=[]
for i in range(0,len(List)):
    for j in range(0,len(List[i])):
        if(List[i][j]==':'):
            if(List[i][0:j] in key_dict):
                for final_num,final_result in enumerate(List[i][j:].split(',')):
                    if(final_result!='\n'):
                        key_dict["%s"%List[i][0:j]]=final_result

print(key_dict)
```

I am using your file in "/home/wangxinshuo/KeyAndObject"

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the content of your file to a dictionary with some oneliner similar to the below one:

```
result = {k:v for k,v in [line.strip().replace(",","").split(":") for line in f if line.strip()]}
```

In case you want the dictionary values to be [stripped](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm), just add `v.strip()`