# Error: nothing to repeat at position

Tags: python, regex, debugging, dictionary

I have a text file which contains a list of slang words and their substitutes in real English. I converted this text file into a dictionary using ":" as a split point, and upon printing the dictionary after the conversion everything seems okay.

However, an error originating from this line: `slangs_re = re.compile('|'.join(slang_dict.keys()))` says `nothing to repeat at position 112207`.

While trying to debug, I found that the error is somehow linked to the dictionary. This is because when I ran the code right below, I didn't get a correct output, but I didn't get an error as well. The expected output for this code is "fitness" but the actual output is "fitess".

```
import re

test = "fitess"

slang_dict = {"fitess":"fitness", "damm":"damn"}

slangs_re = re.compile('|'.join(slang_dict.keys()))

def correct_slang(s, slang_dict=slang_dict):
    def replace(match):
        return slang_dict[match.group(0)]

    return slangs_re.sub(replace, s)

test = correct_slang(test)
print(test)
```

And this is the code with the dictionary (sorry, but the text file is too big to be included. A sample is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023543/convert-a-text-file-into-a-dictionary)). The expected output is "fitness" but the actual output is an error:

```
import re

test = "fitess"

file = open("slang_conversion.txt","r")

slang_dict = {}

for line in file:
    x = line.split(":")
    a = x[0]
    b = x[1]
    c = len(b) - 1

    b = b[0:c]

    slang_dict[a] = b

slangs_re = re.compile('|'.join(slang_dict.keys())) # <-- error

def correct_slang(s, slang_dict=slang_dict):
    def replace(match):
        return slang_dict[match.group(0)]

    return slangs_re.sub(replace, s)

test = correct_slang(test)

print(test)
```

Upon reading other SO threads, I came to know that it's a bug in some cases, but it doesn't seem to be one in this case.

Thank you

Comment: If `slang_dict.keys()` contains regex meta-characters(`*`, `+`, etc.), they need to be escaped.

Comment: Most probably, you can fix it with `r"(?<!\w){}(?!\w)".format('|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in slang_dict.keys()]))`. Or, if all of the words consist of letters, digits and `_`, you may even use `\w+` pattern and check if the key exists in the dictionary before trying to get value.

Comment: Besides, `contractions_re` should be replaced with `slangs_re`. See https://ideone.com/VVR3ke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest replacing

```
slangs_re = re.compile('|'.join(slang_dict.keys()))
```

with

```
slangs_re = re.compile(r"(?<!\w)(?:{})(?!\w)".format('|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in slang_dict])))
```

and make sure you pass the keys sorted by length in the descending order.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import re

test = "fitess no kome*"

slang_dict = {"Aha aha":"no", "fitess":"fitness", "damm":"damn", "kome*":"come", "ow wow":"rrf"}
slang_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(slang_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda x: len(x[0]), reverse=True))

slangs_re = re.compile(r"(?<!\w)(?:{})(?!\w)".format('|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in slang_dict])))
def correct_slang(s, slang_dict=slang_dict):
    def replace(match):
        return slang_dict[match.group(0)]

    return slangs_re.sub(replace, s)

test = correct_slang(test)
print(test)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VIHTEa)

This will check the terms as whole words and will escape the special chars in each of the search phrases so that no issues could occur when passing them to the regular expression engine.

If you are not interested in whole word matching, remove `(?<!\w)` (checking for the leading word boundary) and `(?!\w)` (checking for the trailing word boundary).

Comment: Thanks for this! It's leading to weird errors though. When I'm giving an input _luv 3 iphone awsm display awesome, soo happy_ I expect the output to be _love 3 phone awesome display awesome, soo happy_. However, this is the output:
_love 3 phone awesome displaywhy awesomeohame, isohoh hatehappy_. I've checked for problems in the dictionary, but there are none. What could be the reason for this? Why is awesome becoming awesomeohame?

Comment: @MythicCocoa What is the resulting pattern? Can you share it via http://pastebin.com?

Comment: Did you use `(?<!\w){}(?!\w)`? It looks as if you omitted the whole word check.

Comment: Yes, I did. I'll post it on pastebin, please hold on.

Comment: I did not ask for the code, but for the pattern. Try adding `slang_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(slang_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda x: len(x[0]), reverse=True))` before creating the pattern. Add `from collections import OrderedDict`.

Comment: Could please elaborate on what pattern you mean? Sorry for being a nuisance.

Comment: See the answer.